# Error apache : access denied

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

My configuration :

Wampserver 3.0.0 32bits
Apache 2.4.17
php 5.6.15
mysql 5.7.9

My problem :
WampServer start properly, but when I try to access a project in the log i have:

---

```
[Sat May 21 10:55:39.393866 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 6984:tid 1140] [client 127.0.0.1:50070] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/project/api/app/

[Sat May 21 10:55:39.395878 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 6984:tid 1140] [client 127.0.0.1:50070] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/project/api/src/
```

---

Yet I check my configuration files and all seems OK.

There are my configs files :

httpd.conf :

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
# Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important. Please see
# [httpd.apache.org]
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
# AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#onlineoffline tag - don't remove
#Require local
Require all granted
</Directory>


httpd-vhosts.conf:

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
ServerName localhost.project.com
#ServerAlias localhost.project.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/website/web/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/project/website/web/">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/api"
ServerName api.project.com
#ServerAlias api.project.com
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/project/api">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Demo_websocket/web"
ServerName demo.websocket
#ServerAlias demo.websocket
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/Demo_websocket/web">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file :

> I think I do not understand very well what you mean. The content of my
>   hosts file is :
>   127.0.0.1 localhost
>   127.0.0.1 api.project.com
>   127.0.0.1 localhost.project.com

I already tried to set Require all granted in VirtualHost but no success :s

If someone has already faced this problem and found a solution , I'm interested. Thank you

Comment: What you're doing here is name based virtual hosts. As your testing on localhost, this means that your hosts file should resolve all involved names (localhost.project.com, api.project.com and the others) to 127.0.0.1. And, requests should be made referring to these names, as no host is defined as default Apache will not know who's meant when it receives a request addressed at "127.0.0.1".

Comment: I hope not to say stupid things but I edit my message to add the content of my hosts file.
If I understand what you say , the problem comes from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using localhost with virtual hosting,
if this is your hosts file, it is correct

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.0.1 api.project.com 
127.0.0.1 localhost.project.com
```

and in your local browser you'll write one of these urls.

But your virtual host configuration must respond to a specific host and not to *, for example fo api you must have `<VirtualHost api.project.com:80>` and not `<VirtualHost *:80>`

also the generic * virtual host MUST be at the end of the list, then the result is:

```
<VirtualHost localhost.project.com:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
ServerName localhost.project.com
#ServerAlias localhost.project.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/website/web/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/project/website/web/">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost api.project.com:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project/api"
ServerName api.project.com
#ServerAlias api.project.com
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/project/api">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost demo.websocket:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Demo_websocket/web"
ServerName demo.websocket
#ServerAlias demo.websocket
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/Demo_websocket/web">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@test.fr
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```